# Multiple Exceptions Can't Be Thrown

Tags: java, exception

I'm writing code for practicing setting up a server, but when I'm setting up the Input and Output streams, it says that I have to catch the `IO Exception`. However, I've already caught the exception. Here is the code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Date;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class Server extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TextArea ta = new TextArea();

    Scene scene = new Scene(new ScrollPane(ta), 450, 200);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Server");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    new Thread(() ->
    {
        try
        {
            ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                ta.appendText("Server started at " + new Date() + '\n');

                Socket socket = serversocket.accept();

                DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                while(true)
                {
                    double radius = inputFromClient.readDouble();

                    double area = Math.PI* radius * radius;

                    outputToClient.writeDouble(area);

                    Platform.runLater(() -> { 
                        ta.appendText("Radius received from client: " + radius
                        + '\n');
                        ta.appendText("Area is: " + area + '\n');
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}   
}
```

The first time I call a method that could throw an exception, when setting up the server socket, there is no error detected on the IDE. However, the next time, when I try and set up the socket, and all subsequent times when an exception could happen, the IDE says that I need to catch the exception, even though I thought since it was all in a try/catch block, it was already caught. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It looks like a parenthesis error, you're catch block is outside of the scope of the try.

Comment: no you haven't. Your exception is in your lambda, which is a different scope.

Comment: @user1875195 it is not. the bracket closes the lambda in the `runLater` call

Comment: Alright, so then do I have to catch each exception individually? (Sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm quite a novice at this)

Edit: I just put the try/catch block inside the lambda expression and it worked! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your lambda (starting with the second `() -> {`) is actually the implementation of the [`run()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html#run%28%29) method of `Runnable`, and it doesn't declare any checked exceptions. That means that you have to catch the exception *inside* the lambda. --- FYI: The bad indentation of your code doesn't help us help you, so please get it right next time.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is wrong with my indentation? I thought that indenting every time you made an inner block was all right. Not being sarcastic here, but is there a place which has standard conventions listed so I can use them in the future?